# How much Partition?

Tags: partitioning

i'm a new linux user and I feel like I messed up my Partitions. I have around 600GB to use and it shows I have 5.5 GB of free space, so did I mess up my free space partitioning and would I just need to boot from the CD and change it?

[image]

I wasn't 100% sure on partitioning so  I think I failed >.<

Comment: this is -a- method of partitioning you used. Could you please edit into your question how you want it to be? I know at least 10 different setups that all work but might not suit your methods.

Comment: Oh the 5,5 you are referring to is memory. That is not hard disc space. You have 559 Gb free in / and 17.49 Gb in /home ;) The other one in the line with swap and is not free space too.

Answer (score 0):

That is swap, which has nothing to do with your free space don't worry. /dev/sda2 is where your files and Operating System are stored. Do not touch swap, as it is important for your OS to boot. You don't have to change it, there is nothing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a bit of a problem with this partition scheme (but it's not the memory, which is fine.  You've allocated 571 GiB for / (root) but only 17 GiB for /home, which is possibly back to front from what you intended.

As you can see there's only 12 GiB used on / and it's likely that it will not get much larger than this unless you are going to install a huge database program or just about every other program in the repository.  On the other hand /home is where you be putting all your data (/home/username) and 17 GiB is a little small.

I would suggest you boot off the LiveCD and use gparted to adjust / to be about 25 GiB and use the rest for /home.